# Special Character in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, message

How can i use special characters in java?
They belong under the Cp1252 Character encoding.
I try to use them in a message, but i cant use them.

Characters like: " ︻ー┳═デ "

Comment: Are you trying to write the characters in the source code or e.g. printing them to output? Can you please post some code showing how you try to use the characters.

Comment: Japanese katakana DE is **not** in CP1252

Comment: @ ninjalj when i try to save it, it gives the CP1252 error
@ Nicholas i use an external API. 
player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + victim.getName() + ChatColor.WHITE + "︻デ┳═ー" + ChatColor.RED + attacker.getName());

Comment: Neither are `U+FE3B PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET`, `U+30FC KATAKANA-HIRAGANA PROLONGED SOUND MARK
`, `U+2533 BOX DRAWINGS HEAVY DOWN AND HORIZONTAL`, `U+2550 BOX DRAWINGS DOUBLE HORIZONTAL`

Comment: You SHOULD specify explicitly your output (and input) encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the associated UTF values, for example looking up 'デ' on http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm gives the value of \u30C7 so you can:

```
System.out.println( "\u30C7" );  // as string

System.out.println( '\u30C7' ); // as char
```

Comment: System.out.println(\u30C7); -> Cant resolve
  System.out.println("\u30C7"); -> output: ?

How can i use those UTF properly?

Comment: Okay, Both outputs are ?, how can fix that?

Comment: Change the encoding of the stdout display.

Comment: Sorry im really new to UTF/encoding/characters, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Getting an '?' as the output, indicates that the environment can not render the character properly. In other words, the program works correctly but the visual representation of the character is not present. In what environment are you running your example?

Comment: Where are you outputting the standard out stream?

Comment: Eclipse IDE - Java 7
In just a test class.
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println( '\uFE3B' );
  System.out.println( "\uFE3B" );
 }
output: ? ?

Comment: I have the same setup on windows 7 and it prints fine for me. What OS are you using?

Comment: Win7 (64x), Eclipse IDE Juno
Java 7

Comment: Set console encoding to UTF-8, does this help? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/

Comment: NP. There is a way to set it up for eclipse globally so you don't have to do this for every test separately.

Answer (score 1):

When you use string literals with special characters inside Java code, you must also inform the Java compiler which encoding the Java file itself is encoded with.

Say you edited your Java file (containing the Japanese literal text) and saved it as a UTF-8 file. You *must*, then, tell the compiler to treat the source file as a UTF-8 document:

`javac -encoding UTF-8 file1 file2 ...`

Otherwise, the Java compiler will assume that the Java file is encoded using the operating system's default encoding, which isn't necessarily what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You might wrap `PrintWriter` around `System.out`, to set charset explicitly.

```
final String charset = "UTF-8";
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, charset), true);
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As for the `?` as the character display - It really depends on where you're outputting standard out stream. In standard Ubuntu terminal - it would probably look good (I could test it later). On Windows' `cmd` however, you should manually set the codepage `Chcp` and provide a font that comes with those characters.

Same goes for Eclipse, its console charset is UTF-8 I believe, but if you have no fonts with Japanese characters, it won't help you much.